# Node.JS - shell.mkdir() - Creates random file names instead of taking variable input

Tags: node.js, string, shell, recursion, directory

Good day all,

I've been working on a program for a few weeks now and I'm just come across an error where the filename is not taking the variable given to it. It is creating a random name (ex. 14DZ5I~5)

Here is the code used to create the folders:

```
if (body.folders){
            // Create Parent Folder

            var parentFolder = body.name.trim()  + "/"
            var fullPath = "DOWNLOAD/" + parentFolder
            console.log(parentFolder)

            for(item of body.folders){
                console.log(item.name_with_path.trim())
                var subFolder = "DOWNLOAD/" + item.name_with_path.trim()

                shell.mkdir('-p', subFolder)

                if(item.has_children_folders || item.has_children_files){
                    getFolderFile(PID=PID, FID=item.id, ParentFolder=parentFolder)
                }
            }
```

Please let me know your thoughts!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? What's the parameter you pass to `shell.mkdir` that causes it to create a different directory name?

Comment: I don't know why it's creating the wrong name. The dir parameter is given the string variable subfolder and parentFolder. Most of the time it creates with the correct name, but other times, randomly it creates a random folder name.

Comment: How do you know it's a problem with `mkdir` and that you don't accidentally give it a garbage value due to a bug elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question!

Seems like, on Windows systems, shell.mkdir doesn't like files that end in " " (whitespace). Some strings being fed to the loop ended in " " so I used trim() and replace() in order to mitigate this.

Issue resolved!